# Django Url error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tony'

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, django-urls

I am creating a little Django app with Users and I have created my own UserProfile model.. But I have some issues with my urls(atleast I think).  I think the regular expressions I have used are wrong. Check it out:

the error I get:

```
ValueError at /usr/tony/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tony'
```

My url:

```
url(r'^usr/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'photocomp.apps.users.views.Userprofile'),
```

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from photocomp.apps.users.models import UserProfile

def Userprofile(request, username):
    rc = context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=username)
    return render_to_response("users/UserProfile.html",{'user':u},rc)
```

here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length="30", blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length="30", blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length="30")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to="/avatar")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
u = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

It looks like you are searching for the username attribute of user.  Foreign keys are spanned in django by double underscores.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Also `.get()` will throw a `DoesNotExist` exception it is advisable to wrap the query in try: except block so that it doesn't 500 on the user.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist-and-doesnotexist

```
def Userprofile(request, username):
    rc = context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    try:
      u = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=username)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
      # maybe render an error page?? or an error message at least to the user
      # that the account doesn't exist for that username?
    return render_to_response("users/UserProfile.html",{'user':u},rc)
```

Answer (score 1):

For cleaner code, use [get_object_or 404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def Userprofile(request):
    u = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=1)
```

Also, for clarity, I recommend  not giving your views and classes the same names. I would call this function something like `profile_detail` instead. But that's just a housekeeping detail.